# What factors are also important for block producer to be elected despite votes?

Tags: block-producer, voting, blocks

I'm seeing block producers that are trying to obtain votes as much as they can.

I see **China** in the list more as block producer which made me ask maybe there are other factors helping for election, like having block producer in a country that are rare among other block producers.

- Is that correct?
- What are other factors?

[image: image taken from bloks.io]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People can vote for whoever they want and for whatever reason they want.

Some of the block producers are run by exchanges, and they use their customer's EOS to vote for themselves and their friends.

Some of the block producers offer rewards if you vote for them.

Some of the block producers focus on building products, services, and tools for the community in exchange for votes.

How the votes then get distributed largely falls to how each individual voter perceives that they can get the most value from the system.